# React Material UI deselect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am following [this](http://thrysoee.dk/material-ui/) example to implement a MUI select field im my application. I could get the code to work for me but I have a few problems. It doesn't let me deselect a value which i select. Also i would like to have the ability to add a new value by typing in , if the value is not in the rendered list. Is this possible?

Here is my code :

```
export class FormPage extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {'resource': '', 'catvalues': '', 'subcatvalues': '', 'prodvalues': '', 'solutionValues': '', 'nsocValues': '', 'statusValues': ''};

      this.selectionRenderer1 = this.selectionRenderer1.bind(this);
      this.selectionRenderer2 = this.selectionRenderer2.bind(this);
      this.selectionRenderer3 = this.selectionRenderer3.bind(this);
      this.selectionRenderer4 = this.selectionRenderer4.bind(this);
      this.selectionRenderer5 = this.selectionRenderer5.bind(this);
      this.selectionRenderer6 = this.selectionRenderer6.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.addResource = this.addResource.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange1 = (event, key, catvalues) => {
      this.setState({catvalues});
    };

    selectionRenderer1 = catvalues => {
      // change the default comma separated rendering
      return (
          <span style={{color: '#ff4081'}}>
              {catvalues.join('; ')}
          </span>
      ).bind(this);
    };

    menuItems1(catvalues) {
      return categorylist.map(cl => (
          <MenuItem
              key={cl}
              insetChildren
              checked={catvalues.includes(cl)}
              value={cl}
              primaryText={cl}
          />
      ));
    }

    handleChange2 = (event, key, subcatvalues) => {
      this.setState({subcatvalues});
    };

    selectionRenderer2 = subcatvalues => {
      // change the default comma separated rendering
      return (
          <span style={{color: '#ff4081'}}>
              {subcatvalues.join('; ')}
          </span>
      );
    };

    menuItems2(subcatvalues) {
      return subcategorylist.map(scl => (
          <MenuItem
              key={scl}
              insetChildren
              checked={subcatvalues.includes(scl)}
              value={scl}
              primaryText={scl}
          />
      ));
    }

    handleChange3 = (event, key, prodvalues) => {
      this.setState({prodvalues});
    };

    selectionRenderer3 = prodvalues => {
      // change the default comma separated rendering
      return (
          <span style={{color: '#ff4081'}}>
              {prodvalues.join('; ')}
          </span>
      ).bind(this);
    };

    menuItems3(prodvalues) {
      return prodlist.map(pl => (
          <MenuItem
              key={pl}
              insetChildren
              checked={prodvalues.includes(pl)}
              value={pl}
              primaryText={pl}
          />
      ));
    }

    handleChange4 = (event, key, solutionValues) => {
      this.setState({solutionValues});
    };

    selectionRenderer4 = solutionValues => {
      // change the default comma separated rendering
      return (
          <span style={{color: '#ff4081'}}>
                          {solutionValues.join('; ')}
                  </span>
      ).bind(this);
    };

    menuItems4(solutionValues) {
      return solutionList.map(sl => (
          <MenuItem
              key={sl}
              insetChildren
              checked={solutionValues.includes(sl)}
              value={sl}
              primaryText={sl}
          />
      ));
    }

    handleChange5 = (event, key, nsocValues) => {
      this.setState({nsocValues});
    };

    selectionRenderer5 = nsocValues => {
      // change the default comma separated rendering
      return (
          <span style={{color: '#ff4081'}}>
                          {nsocValues.join('; ')}
                  </span>
      ).bind(this);
    };

    menuItems5(nsocValues) {
      return nsocList.map(nl => (
          <MenuItem
              key={nl}
              insetChildren
              checked={nsocValues.includes(nl)}
              value={nl}
              primaryText={nl}
          />
      ));
    }

    handleChange6 = (event, key, statusValues) => {
      this.setState({statusValues});
    };

    selectionRenderer6 = statusValues => {
      // change the default comma separated rendering
      return (
          <span style={{color: '#ff4081'}}>
                          {statusValues.join('; ')}
                  </span>
      ).bind(this);
    };

    menuItems6(statusValues) {
      return statusList.map(sll => (
          <MenuItem
              key={sll}
              insetChildren
              checked={statusValues.includes(sll)}
              value={sll}
              primaryText={sll}
          />
      ));
    }

    addResource(resource) {
      console.log('Adding resource:', resource);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', url: '/api/resources', contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(resource),
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          browserHistory.push('/home');
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          // ideally, show error to user.
          console.log('Error adding resource:', err);
        }
      });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = document.forms.resourceAdd;
      this.addResource({
        category: form.category.value,
        subcategory: form.subcategory.value,
        product: form.product.value,
        solution: form.solution.value,
        weight: form.weight.value,
        nsoc: form.nsoc.value,
        status: form.status.value,
        date_product_added: form.date_product_added.value,
        design_status: form.design_status.value,
        design_combined: form.design_combined.value,
        implement_status: form.implement_status.value,
        implement_combined: form.implement_combined.value,
        operate_status: form.operate_status.value,
        operate_combined: form.operate_combined.value});
      // clear the form for the next input
      form.category.value = ''; form.subcategory.value = ''; form.product.value = ''; form.solution.value = ''; form.weight.value = ''; form.nsoc.value = ''; form.status.value = '';form.date_product_added.value = '';
      form.design_status.value = ''; form.design_combined.value = ''; form.implement_status.value = ''; form.implement_combined.value = ''; form.operate_status.value = ''; form.operate_combined.value = '';
    }

    render() {
      const {catvalues} = this.state;
      const floatingLabelText1 = 'Categories' +
          (catvalues.length > 1 ? ` (${catvalues.length})` : '');

      const {subcatvalues} = this.state;
      const floatingLabelText2 = 'Sub Categories' +
          (subcatvalues.length > 1 ? ` (${subcatvalues.length})` : '');

      const {prodvalues} = this.state;
      const floatingLabelText3 = 'Products' +
          (prodvalues.length > 1 ? ` (${prodvalues.length})` : '');

      const {solutionValues} = this.state;
      const floatingLabelText4 = 'Solutions' +
          (solutionValues.length > 1 ? ` (${solutionValues.length})` : '');

      const {nsocValues} = this.state;
      const floatingLabelText5 = 'NSOC' +
          (nsocValues.length > 1 ? ` (${nsocValues.length})` : '');

      const {statusValues} = this.state;
      const floatingLabelText6 = 'Status' +
          (statusValues.length > 1 ? ` (${statusValues.length})` : '');

      return (
        <PageBase title="Form Page"
                  navigation="Application / Form Page">
                                                  <form>

                                                      <SelectField
                              multiple
                              floatingLabelText={floatingLabelText1}
                              fullwidth={true}
                              value={catvalues}
                              onChange={this.handleChange1}
                              selectionRenderer={this.selectionRenderer1}
                          >
                                                              {this.menuItems1(catvalues)}
                                                      </SelectField>

                                                      <SelectField
                              multiple
                              floatingLabelText={floatingLabelText2}
                              fullwidth
                              value={subcatvalues}
                              onChange={this.handleChange2}
                              selectionRenderer={this.selectionRenderer2}
                          >
                                                              {this.menuItems2(subcatvalues)}
                                                      </SelectField>

                                                      <SelectField
                              multiple
                              floatingLabelText={floatingLabelText3}
                              fullwidth
                              value={prodvalues}
                              onChange={this.handleChange3}
                              selectionRenderer={this.selectionRenderer3}
                          >
                                                              {this.menuItems3(prodvalues)}
                                                      </SelectField>

                                                    <SelectField
                                                        multiple
                                                        floatingLabelText={floatingLabelText4}
                                                        fullwidth
                                                        value={solutionValues}
                                                        onChange={this.handleChange4}
                                                        selectionRenderer={this.selectionRenderer4}
                                                    >
                                                        {this.menuItems4(solutionValues)}
                                                    </SelectField>

                                                          <TextField
                hintText="Weight"
                floatingLabelText="Weight"
                fullWidth
            />

                                                    <SelectField
                                                        multiple
                                                        floatingLabelText={floatingLabelText5}
                                                        fullwidth
                                                        value={nsocValues}
                                                        onChange={this.handleChange5}
                                                        selectionRenderer={this.selectionRenderer5}
                                                    >
                                                        {this.menuItems5(nsocValues)}
                                                    </SelectField>


                                                    <SelectField
                                                        multiple
                                                        floatingLabelText={floatingLabelText6}
                                                        fullwidth
                                                        value={statusValues}
                                                        onChange={this.handleChange6}
                                                        selectionRenderer={this.selectionRenderer6}
                                                    >
                                                        {this.menuItems6(statusValues)}
                                                    </SelectField>

                                                          <DatePicker
                hintText="Date Product Added"
                floatingLabelText="date_product_added"
                fullWidth/>

                                                          <TextField
                hintText="Design Status"
                floatingLabelText="design_status"
                fullWidth
            />

                                                          <TextField
                hintText="Design Players"
                floatingLabelText="design_combined"
                fullWidth
            />

                                                          <TextField
                hintText="Implement Status"
                floatingLabelText="implement_status"
                fullWidth
            />

                                                          <TextField
                hintText="Implement Players"
                floatingLabelText="implement_combined"
                fullWidth
            />

                                                          <TextField
                hintText="Operate Status"
                floatingLabelText="operate_status"
                fullWidth
            />

                                                          <TextField
                hintText="Operate Players"
                floatingLabelText="operate_players"
                fullWidth
            />



                                                          <Divider/>

                                                          <div style={styles.buttons}>
                                                                  <Link to="/">
                                                                          <RaisedButton label="Cancel"/>
                                                                  </Link>

                                                                  <RaisedButton label="Save"
                            style={styles.saveButton}
                            type="submit"
                            onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
                            primary/>
                                                          </div>
                                                  </form>
                                          </PageBase>

    );
    }
}

export default FormPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you target different behaviors depending on the event sent to your component (a click event triggers normal behavior, a double-click switch to an input that adds a name to a collection) or add a second component either before or after your select that does the same (think like a button group and the *pre-* or *post-button* triggers the switch).

You can then switch between the component you're rendering in your `render` using the current `state`.

Your component looks a bit big to me. I would try and break it into subcomponent (the numbered event handlers especially look like they could be props of subcomponents).

**EDIT**

[See this CodePen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/NvMLNg).
It's a fork from a former example I coded using Foundation 6. The same principle applies to Material-UI, though, as the gist of it concerns ReactJS.
Listening to double clicks on the select input didn't work :p. I added a button that changed the component's state. The render method of the parent component switches on that state and renders different inputs accordingly.

I used this *trick* to toggle between read-only fields and input field, depending on the rights of the user, on other projects. The double click works perfectly on that use case and makes for a super user experience.

```
  ...

  switchComponent(){
    this.setState({
      inputShown : !this.state.inputShown
    });
  }

  render() {
    const children = this.state.inputShown ? 
      (<Input label="Add: " id="input1" onChange={this.inputChanged} className="columns small-4" />)
          :
      (<Select label="Choose: " id="select1" onChange={this.selectChanged} className="columns small-4">
          {this.state.options.map((o,i) => <Option key={i} label={o} defaultValue={o}/>)}
        </Select>)
    return <div>
      <div className="row">
        <a className="button primary columns small-1" onClick={this.switchComponent}>Switch</a>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>;
  }

  ...
```

*NB* The CSS isn't tweaked at all, it is stock Foundation 6. You can *bind* the switch button and the select/input with CSS easily though.